# React extends keyword webpack failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am beginner to React, when I compile the code below it gives error.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar'

const API_KEY = '';

// this component should produce some html
// Some HTML

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar/>
        </div>
    )
};

// aciklama
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

search_bar.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const SearchBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return <input />;
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

I started npm server from terminal, it gives the error in the below link:

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vURT.png)

ERROR in ./src/components/search_bar.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:16)
webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: Hi! Please include errors messages **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: and don't post your API keys here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo

```
class SearchBar extends Component {  //fixed
    render(){
        return <input />;
    }
}
```

change from `const` to `class`

Answer (score 1):

A const extend a class. It has to be a class itself. So, `const`  should be changed to `class`.